# Latex \binom with other types of brackets

Tags: math-mode

I want to write (in math mode) `\binom{a}{b}` with square brackets `[`

I know that `{a\brack b}` exists for this, but somehow it doesn't work with me. Is there another way to generate what I want?

Comment: Actually, my problem is solved. I'm using someone else's tex file and they are defining `\renewcommand{\atopwithdelims}[2]{{\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}_F}`. After deleting this, all worked fine.

Comment: ***Don't*** redefine primitives.

Comment: But I didn't do it :)

Answer (score 9):

The `\binom` command is defined by `amsmath` with

```
\newcommand{\binom}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

(not really like this but it's essentially equivalent).

I wouldn't redefine `\binom`, but rather `\stirling`:

```
\newcommand{\stirling}[2]{\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

The third argument is the fraction line thickness, the first two are the required delimiters; the fourth argument can be used to force a math style, say

```
\newcommand{\dstirling}[2]{\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}
```

in analogy with `\dfrac`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will probably solve it (though my problem is already solved, see my comment above).